# If a derived class has a method with a signature that is exactly the same as signature from a method in the base class, does it generate a vtable?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overriding, virtual, vtable

I recently watched a YouTube video from ["**Low Level Learning**"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aq365yzrTVE&t=2s) where, at `03:38`, it was mentioned that "functions with the same signature in the derived class are virtual in the parent by default." I'm unsure if I misunderstood, but it seems to imply that when a derived class has a method with the same signature as one in the parent class, the method in the parent class becomes virtual, even if the `virtual` keyword is not explicitly used.

I have a few questions that formed in my mind regarding this statement:

1. Is the statement true? Does having functions with the same signature in the derived class make them automatically virtual in the parent class?
2. Additionally, is it valid to use `sizeof()` on a base class to determine if a parent-derived class uses a vtable?

To verify my understanding of this, I created the following program in C++:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
    int num;

    Base(int num) : num(num) {}

    void greet() {
        std::cout << "Hello " << num << " from Base Class\n";
    }

    float operator()(int n) const { return n * num; }
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    float num;

    Derived(float num) : Base(1), num(num) {}

    void greet() {
        std::cout << "Hello " << num << " from Derived Class\n";
    }

    float operator()(int n) const { return n * num; }
};

int main() {
    Base base(5);
    Derived derived(8.8);

    base.greet();
    derived.greet();

    std::cout << "sizeof(base)    = " << sizeof(base) << "\n";
    std::cout << "sizeof(derived) = " << sizeof(derived) << "\n";

    std::cout << "base(3)    = " << base(3) << "\n";
    std::cout << "derived(3) = " << derived(3) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Based on my understanding, if a class uses a vtable, it should result in a different expected `sizeof()` value compared to a class without a vtable. However, in my program, the size remains unchanged, whereas declaring some parent class methods as virtual does increase the size.

I would appreciate clarification on these questions and an explanation. Thank you!

Comment: _functions with the same signature in the derived class are virtual in the parent by default_ This is categorically untrue.  The only way to make a function `virtual`, is to declare it as such.

Comment: Don't get hung up on "uses a vtable"; that's an implementation detail. What matters is that marking a function `virtual` makes it a virtual function; if a base class function is not marked `virtual` it isn't virtual, regardless of what a derived class might do. If it is marked `virtual` then it's virtual and in all derived classes that provide a function with the same signature it's virtual, regardless of whether the derived class marks it `virtual`.

Comment: This looks like some C guru that tries hard to write really bad C++ code, to "prove" that C code is 20% faster. He just forgets to tell you that his Super fast "well written C" compiles as C++ as well. And runs just as fast.

Comment: I think what he meant to say was "Functions in the derived class are implicitly virtual, _if they have the same signature as a virtual function in the parent class_"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the statement true? Does having functions with the same signature in the derived class make them automatically virtual in the parent class?

No, this is false.

> Additionally, is it valid to use sizeof() on a base class to determine if a parent-derived class uses a vtable?

`sizeof` does not reflect, or has anything to do with anything called a "vtable". Not only that, but in the two thousand pages that make up the current C++ standard you will not find a single mention of anything that's described as a "vtable".

If you review my posting history on Stackoverflow you will find me repeatedly saying this: any clown can upload a video to Youtube, or publish random, rambling hallucinations on some blog. Even I can do that. And I did.

If your goal is to learn C++, you will not succeed, very much, by watching random videos or trying to do random coding puzzles. The only time-tested, proven method of learning the most complicated and hardest to learn general purpose programming language in use today is [from a good, reputable textbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). It takes money to publish a textbook and no publisher will risk losing a sizable chunk of change on dead trees without vetting, thoroughly, the source material. There is not much of a vetting process for uploaded Youtube videos, or publishing a web site.